# How could you prevent height resize on input focus on mobile for a fullheight PWA?

Tags: css, android-softkeyboard

I have this case when I would like the PWA to be always the same 100vh even when an input is focused from a mobile device and the client keyboard appears.

As of now the whole 100vh concept breaks with a keyboard open as in this image:
[image]

Anybody has any clue to a solution?(without JS if possible)

Comment: How would be your desired output? Do you want to zoom out the document to fit the residual? or stick to the bottom (current default of browsers)? or stick to the top?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I was thinking of just cutting it without any extra scroll, similar to an Android app experience when a keyboard for input pops up

Comment: You can simulate the desired result by setting `overflow-y:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with this CSS you could achieve what you  want

```
   :root {
       --body-size: 100vh;
    }
    body{
        height:var(--body-size);
     }
    @Media only screen and (max-width : 400px) {
        input:focus{
          --body-size: 50vh;
        }
     }
```

Comment: it's not quite the solution given that the content isn't supposed to scroll give that an app like experience is in mind

Comment: any solution found for this @Eugene?

Comment: Indeed - any solution!?